# PHP anonymous function causes syntax error on some installations

Tags: syntax-error, php, anonymous-function

I have the following code:

```
    $file_check_method_func = function($n) {
        $n = absint($n);
        if(1 !== $n) { $n = 0; }
        return $n;
    };
    $valid['file_check_method'] = array_map($file_check_method_func, $input['file_check_method']);
```

This works on my PHP 5.3.5 installation but when I run this code on a PHP 5.2.15 installation I get:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/xxxx/public_html/xxxx/xxxxxxx/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-file-monitor-plus/classes/wpfmp.settings.class.php on line 220
```

Line 220 being the first line of the above code.

So my question(s), is there something wrongly written in my code that would give this error? If not is it because of a bug or not supported feature in PHP 5.2.15? If yes then how can I write the above code so not to generate the error?

The above code is in a function in a class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anonymous functions is a feature added in 5.3

For earlier versions, create a named function and refer it by name. Eg.:

```
function file_check_method_func($n) {
    $n = absint($n);
    if(1 !== $n) { $n = 0; }
    return $n;
}
$valid['file_check_method'] = array_map('file_check_method_func', $input['file_check_method']);
```

or inside a class:

```
class Foo {
  protected function file_check_method_func($n) {
    $n = absint($n);
    if(1 !== $n) { $n = 0; }
    return $n;
  }
  function validate($input) {
    $valid = array();
    $valid['file_check_method'] = array_map(array($this, 'file_check_method_func'), $input['file_check_method']);
    return $valid;
  }
}
```

I would strongly suggest *not*  to rely on `create_function`.

Comment: @Raffael They are not really anonymous - the name is just created in runtime, but technically `create_function` is just a wrapper around `eval` + a random name generator.

Comment: @troelskn - My code is inside a class I cannot pass just the function name as it wont find it.

Comment: @Brady, if you define a method in the current class, you can refer to it with `array($this, 'method_name')`. Take a look at the PHP manual page about [callbacks](http://php.net/callback).

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for anonymous functions in the example can only be used in PHP >= 5.3. Before PHP 5.3, anonymous functions can only be created with [`create_function()`](http://php.net/create_function).

Comment: Right. Updated answer. I always found `create_function()` incredibly ugly and I used it so rarely that I didn't even think about it now.

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous functions using this function-syntax has been added 5.3. But you can define anonymous functions using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php