# Filter multidimensional array based on partial match of search value

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, filtering, partial-matches

I'm looking for a function where given this array:

```
array(
 [0] =>
  array(
   ['text'] =>'I like Apples'
   ['id'] =>'102923'
 )
 [1] =>
  array(
   ['text'] =>'I like Apples and Bread'
   ['id'] =>'283923'
 )
 [2] =>
  array(
  ['text'] =>'I like Apples, Bread, and Cheese'
  ['id'] =>'3384823'
 )
 [3] =>
  array(
  ['text'] =>'I like Green Eggs and Ham'
  ['id'] =>'4473873'
 ) 
etc..
```

I want to search for the needle

> "Bread"

and get the following result

```
[1] =>
  array(
   ['text'] =>'I like Apples and Bread'
   ['id'] =>'283923'
 )
 [2] =>
  array(
  ['text'] =>'I like Apples, Bread, and Cheese'
  ['id'] =>'3384823'
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). You can provide a callback which decides which elements remain in the array and which should be removed. (A return value of `false` from the callback indicates that the given element should be removed.) Something like this:

```
$search_text = 'Bread';

array_filter($array, function($el) use ($search_text) {
        return ( strpos($el['text'], $search_text) !== false );
    });
```

For more information:

- [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter)
- [`strpos` return values](http://php.net/strpos#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues)

Comment: Better use `strpos(…) !== FALSE`. This saves a function call and this is faster.

Comment: Thanks Hans, out of curiosity what is the 'use' operator? Is it like the 'as' operator in an each loop? I can't find any info about it.

Comment: The `use` keyword makes the variables you give it available in the function's scope. By default, inside that function `$search_text` would be undefined, and so we write `use` to have PHP "carry over" the variable into the local scope.

Comment: Why do I keep getting this error? `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION` I even tried copying the example straight from [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#100813)

Comment: @gavsiu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6412032/php-anonymous-function-causes-syntax-error-on-some-installations

Comment: @JonGauthier  How to find text but return id?

Answer (score 3):

From PHP8, there is a new function to return a boolean value to express whether a substring occurs in a string (this is offered as a simpler replacement for `strpos()`).

[str_contains()](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/str_contains)

If case-insensitivity is needed, then `str_contains()`'s case-sensitive matching will not suffice. Use `stripos()`:

```
stripos($subarray['text'], $search) !== false
```

If word boundaries are needed then use a regular expression with `\b` metacharacters.

This would need to be called within an iterating function/construct.

From PHP7.4 arrow functions can be used reduce the overall syntax and invite global variables into the custom function's scope.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ntMfF))

```
$array = [
    ['text' => 'I like Apples', 'id' => '102923'],
    ['text' => 'I like Apples and Bread', 'id' =>'283923'],
    ['text' => 'I like Apples, Bread, and Cheese', 'id' => '3384823'],
    ['text' => 'I like Green Eggs and Ham', 'id' =>'4473873']
];

$search = 'Bread';
var_export(
    array_filter($array, fn($subarray) => str_contains($subarray['text'], $search))
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 
  array (
    'text' => 'I like Apples and Bread',
    'id' => '283923',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'text' => 'I like Apples, Bread, and Cheese',
    'id' => '3384823',
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

is there a reason for multi array. is id unique and can it be used as index.

```
$data=array(

  array(
   'text' =>'I like Apples',
   'id' =>'102923'
 )
,
  array(
   'text' =>'I like Apples and Bread',
   'id' =>'283923'
 )
,
  array(
  'text' =>'I like Apples, Bread, and Cheese',
  'id' =>'3384823'
 )
,
  array(
  'text' =>'I like Green Eggs and Ham',
  'id' =>'4473873'
 )

 );
```

$findme='bread';

```
 foreach ($data as $k=>$v){

 if(stripos($v['text'], $findme) !== false){
 echo "id={$v[id]} text={$v[text]}<br />"; // do something $newdata=array($v[id]=>$v[text])
 }

 }
```