# Filter array to retain all elements that have a key containing a searched string

Tags: php, substring, key, filtering

I'm trying to do some predictive searching, and I am using `preg_grep()` as a way to get away from the `LIKE` in SQL.

I have the following array:

```
$values = array("Phorce" => 123, "Billy" => 234);
```

If I have `Phorc` I want all array elements (key and value), with a partial match of `Phorc`, so here `Phorce => 123`. Is this possible with `preg_grep()` ?

I have tried to use the following:

```
$result = preg_grep('~' . 'Phorce' . '~', $values);
```

How can I get my code to work as described above?

Comment: Add the code you have tried.

Comment: Let me better understand what you're doing. If a table contains a 1,000 rows, you will get them all ... and then filter them in PHP, rather than filtering them with SQL?

Comment: @Augwa I have updated this.

Comment: @Phorce that doesn't answer my question. Why are you trying to avoid the LIKE in SQL?

Comment: @Augwa Instead of using SQL. I have an array of values (names) and each of these values have an id so `Phorce => 1234` what I want to do is, search through this array for all the possibilities that contain for example `Phor` so if someone passed in this value, it would then return `Phorce`

Comment: Duplicate that is only missing the `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` flag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932438/search-for-partial-value-match-in-an-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to search the keys then?

```
$values = array("Phorce" => 123, "Billy" => 234);
$results = preg_grep('/Phor/', array_keys($values));

$arr = [];
foreach($results as $result) {
    $arr[$result] = $values[$result];
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Thank you! This works :)! The only problem is, I want to return the key values as well as the keys? .. This seems to only give the keys and not the values

Comment: @Rizier123 answer does just that, but I'll update mine to make it it include them as well.

Comment: Too many loops in this answer.  Use Rizier's non-regex filter.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

Here I just use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) combined with [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to search through each array key if it contains the search value.

```
<?php

    $array = array("Phorce" => 123, "Billy" => 234);

    $search = "Phor";
    $arr = array_filter($array, function($k)use($search){
        return stripos($k, $search) !== FALSE;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [Phorce] => 123
)
```

<sub>Before someone says, that it doesn't work: You need PHP 5.6, so if you don't have that *upgrade!*</sub>

Comment: I haven't been able to find a dupe to close with.  Perhaps update your answer to mention `str_contains()` in PHP8.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code to get Response:

[Demo Code](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yp7hjg23)

```
<?php
$values = array("Phorce" => 123, "Billy" => 234);

var_export(
    array_filter(
        $values,
        function($haystack ) {
          if (is_numeric(strpos($haystack, 'Phorce'))) {
            return $haystack;
          } 
        },
        ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
    )
);
```