# How to get result by search from an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img src='http://dev-gym-management.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/images-5
.jpg' height='50px' width='50px' class='img-circle'/>
            [1] => Anna Khan
            [2] => Personal Trainer
            [3] => anna@gmail.com
            [4] => 990099000
            [5] => <a href='?page=gmgt_staff&tab=add_staffmember&action=edit&staff_member_id=5 class
='btn btn-info'>Edit</a><a href='?page=gmgt_staff&tab=staff_memberlist&action=delete&staff_member_id
=5' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img src='http://dev-gym-management.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/images-4
.jpg' height='50px' width='50px' class='img-circle'/>
            [1] => Jobaer Rahman
            [2] => Personal Trainer
            [3] => jobaer@gmail.com
            [4] => 55555555
            [5] => <a href='?page=gmgt_staff&tab=add_staffmember&action=edit&staff_member_id=3 class
='btn btn-info'>Edit</a><a href='?page=gmgt_staff&tab=staff_memberlist&action=delete&staff_member_id
=3' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a>
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img src='http://dev-gym-management.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/images-3
.jpg' height='50px' width='50px' class='img-circle'/>
            [1] => Milon Khan
            [2] => Fitness Instructors
            [3] => milon@gmail.com
            [4] => 7777777888
            [5] => <a href='?page=gmgt_staff&tab=add_staffmember&action=edit&staff_member_id=4 class
='btn btn-info'>Edit</a><a href='?page=gmgt_staff&tab=staff_memberlist&action=delete&staff_member_id
=4' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a>
        )

)
```

Now If I want to search by "Anna Khan" I need results like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <img src='http://dev-gym-management.pantheonsite.io/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/images-5
.jpg' height='50px' width='50px' class='img-circle'/>
            [1] => Anna Khan
            [2] => Personal Trainer
            [3] => anna@gmail.com
            [4] => 990099000
            [5] => <a href='?page=gmgt_staff&tab=add_staffmember&action=edit&staff_member_id=5 class
='btn btn-info'>Edit</a><a href='?page=gmgt_staff&tab=staff_memberlist&action=delete&staff_member_id
=5' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a>
        )   

)
```

I'm trying with search array but not working properly. For reducing complexity i don't use raw code. any easiest way or php array function for do this?

Comment: Take look in the example http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#116635

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932438/search-for-partial-value-match-in-an-array   I think you need to see this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = [array here];
$search_str = 'Anna Khan';

array_walk_recursive($data, function($item, $key) use ($search_str) {
   if (stripos($item, $search_str) !== false) {
       echo $key; // or any action you want.
   }
});
```