# Look for specific number in list and echo that lines containing that number

Tags: php

I have to get a output of a list that only contain ports like :8080, not any other ports so the php has to check if the website contains any lines with :8080 port, and if so you will have to print the whole line.

```
$url = "https://proxymagic.cc/Home/FreeProxies?accesskey=key";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$lines = explode('
', $str);
foreach($lines as $line) {
  if (stripos($line, '8080') !== false) {
    $line = $output;
  }

echo $output;

}
```

Comment: What's your problem? This code looks like it would work

Comment: Well `$line = $output;` should be `$output .= $line;` ,but the rest is good

Comment: I'm getting this output right now: http://mrkevko.nl/proxies/.

Comment: It shouldn't be that many lines, so it checks to much I guess & it won't begin on a new line each time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are storing the line if you just want to echo it back out. This will echo each matching line on a separate line.

```
$url = "https://proxymagic.cc/Home/FreeProxies?accesskey=key";
$str = file_get_contents($url);
$lines = explode('
', $str);


foreach($lines as $line) {
  if (stripos($line, '8080') !== false) {
    echo $line . "\n<br/>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php) instead of `file_get_contents()`.
2. Use [`array_filter`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), as [Jon Gauthier demonstrates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6932467) in his answer to a related question:

   ```
   array_filter($array, function($el) use ($search_text) {
      return ( strpos($el['text'], $search_text) !== false );
   });
   ```
3. Summary:

   ```
   $url = "https://proxymagic.cc/Home/FreeProxies?accesskey=key";
   $lines = file($url);

   $needle = ':8080';
   $lines = array_filter($lines, function($line) use ($needle) {
      return false !== strpos($line, $needle);
   });

   print_r($lines);
   ```

Comment: I already googled alot before I posted this thread... And it doesn't look like this works, read above what the current problem is.